# How do I round up a date?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table that contains the contract information for our customers.  I need to round up the contract maturity date to a certain day of the month depending on the contract date itself.  For example, if the contract date is 01-05-2016 I need to round it up to 01-10-2016.  If the contract date is 01-11-2016 I need to round it up to 01-20-2016.  And finally, if the contract date is 01-21-2016 I need to round it up to 01-30-2016.  These round up dates match our billing cycles and I need all of our contracts to fall within one of these billing cycles.  All dates are a DATETIME data type.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these always using 10 day increments starting from 10th of the month? And what's the last contract date for February?

Comment: so what's the rule for 2/21/2016?  2/28? or 2/29?   What about 1/31/2016?  2/10?  Sounds like a great opportunity for a calendar table.

Comment: Do it with DATEADD() and DATEDIFF().

Comment: What to do with dates that are after February 20th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
DECLARE @testData TABLE(TestDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @testData VALUES({d'2016-02-05'}),({d'2016-02-12'}),({d'2016-02-21'});

SELECT TestDate
      ,CASE WHEN DAY(TestDate) BEtWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 1
            WHEN DAY(TestDate) BEtWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 2 
            ELSE 3 END AS BillingCycle
      ,CASE WHEN DAY(TestDate) BEtWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(TestDate) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(TestDate),2),' ','0')+'01'  AS DATE)
            WHEN DAY(TestDate) BEtWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(TestDate) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(TestDate),2),' ','0') +'11'  AS DATE) 
            ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(TestDate) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(TestDate),2),' ','0')+'28'  AS DATE) END AS BillingCycleDate
FROM @testData
```

The result:

```
TestDate    BillingCycle    BillingCycleDate
2016-02-05      1               2016-02-01
2016-02-12      2               2016-02-11
2016-02-21      3               2016-02-28
```

Comment: I made a mistake.  Billing Cycle 3 would always be the 28th of each month.  That's how we avoid the problem.

Comment: @user3712737 That makes it even simpler! See my edits!

Answer (score 0):

You would do much better to avoid casting dates from strings. The long way is something like this though I'm sure it could be shortened and obfuscated. You did not specify what to do with dates after the 28th though:

```
dateadd(
    day,
    case day(contract_dt)
        when  1 then 9
        when  2 then 8
        ...
        when 10 then 0
        when 11 then 9
        when 12 then 8
        ...
        when 20 then 0
        when 21 then 7
        when 22 then 6
        ...
        when 28 then 0
        when 29 then -1
        when 30 then -2
        when 31 then -3
    end,
    contract_dt
)
```

Here is one of the more compact forms I alluded to:

```
dateadd(day, case
    when day(contract_dt) <= 20
    then 10 - day(contract_dt) % 10
    else 28 - day(contract_dt)
end, contract_dt)
```

**EDIT:** I presume based on your acceptance of the other answer that you want to fall back to the 28th for the outliers and so I edited the above accordingly.

Comment: Ok.  I have got my contract date with the correct dates thanks to your help, now I need to do the same thing with the Next Payment Due Date.  The problem I have is that this is a computed field.  I created a CTE to compute the Next Payment Due Date, but when I tried to apply your fix to round up the date, I get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".  The CTE computes the Next Payment Due Date as follows:

Comment: cteNextDueDate (DocNmbr, NextDueDate)
 AS
 (SELECT dbo.RM20101.DOCNUMBR,
         CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),DATEADD (MONTH, -((RM20101.CURTRXAM / (CONVERT(MONEY,CVS.PmtAmt))) -1), RM20101.DUEDATE), 111) AS NextDueDate
FROM dbo.RM20101
INNER JOIN dbo.SOP30200 ON dbo.RM20101.DOCNUMBR = dbo.SOP30200.SOPNUMBE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SY90000 ON dbo.SY90000.ObjectID = SOP30200.SOPNUMBE AND dbo.SY90000.ObjectType = 'SalesPaymentTermsEntry' AND dbo.SY90000.PropertyName = 'MonthlyPayments'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePaymentsRemaining AS CVS ON dbo.SY90000.ObjectID = CVS.ObjectID)

Comment: CASE WHEN DAY(DUDT.DocNmbr) BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(DUDT.DocNmbr) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DUDT.DocNmbr),2),' ','0')+'10' AS DATE)
       WHEN DAY(DUDT.DocNmbr) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(DUDT.DocNmbr) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DUDT.DocNmbr),2),' ','0')+'20' AS DATE) 
       ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(DUDT.DocNmbr) AS CHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DUDT.DocNmbr),2),' ','0')+'28' AS DATE)
  END AS NextDueDate,

Comment: @user3712737 That's why the string approach is bad.

Comment: I have found my error.  Thanks everyone for your help!!

Comment: @user3712737 I'm still curious to know what you're doing with the dates at the end of the month.